# How I can use Certificate.pfx for windows exe build

Tags: c#, sign

I have `Visual Studio Project` for **C-Sharp Form application**.
On my side, my application is working, but it is dangerous in other's computer.
So, I need sign my application with some certification.

I have `cert.pfx` file and it's password.
How I can use it for my solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the signtool from Windows SDK:

> Sign Tool is a command-line tool that digitally signs files, verifies
>   signatures in files, and time-stamps files.
>
> This tool is automatically installed with Visual Studio.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe

Comment: Pleas refer to [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and provide context to your link.

Comment: @RaulSebastian Thank you for pointing to the guide. I have edited my answer.